# two simple string operation in objective-c (shift operating and iterating)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to manipulate NSString in obj-c here is what I want to do :

iterate a string though a for-each / for loop and shift left (<<) each character of NSString
but I don't know how should I iterate through the NSString's characters and how to use shift operator in obj-c.

I'm fairly new in objective-c .

regards

Comment: There is no shift operator for strings in C or Objective-C.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I answered how to loop through the characters. Please clarify the `<<` step you require.

Comment: Why do you need to shift characters? What's the [overall goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I want to create a simple encryption using shift operators <</>> is there any possibility of converting chars to int then shift then and then revert to char in obj-c?

Comment: @Austin: better, but still not a complete description of the overall goal. Why do you want to encrypt the string? Is this purely educational, or do you want to put your encryption to use for something else? As for converting characters to integers, there's no need. `char` (and `unichar`) are already integer types. Be careful about truncation.

Comment: @outis , I want to store some info on my app but need to do some simple encryption/decryption I guess I need a reference about methods in "foundation" something better than dev.apple . I come from MS world and you know msdn is how easy , but still uncomfy with apple's doc do you have any other suggestion instead of using apple's doc?

Comment: @Austin: use Google. Apple's documentation is the only definitive one, though [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/) has additional info. As for protecting data, you shouldn't implement your own encryption scheme unless you really, really, *really* know what you're doing. It's easy to get wrong. Instead, search for [existing encryption libraries](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/198285-encryption-frameworks-in-cocoa.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString`s are immutable; [`mutableCopyWithZone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSMutableCopying/mutableCopyWithZone%3a) will get you an ([implicitly retained](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)) `NSMutableString`. However, `NSMutableString` doesn't have a way of setting individual characters. It would be easier to get an array of characters using one of the many methods (e.g. [`getCharacters:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCharacters%3arange%3a) for wide characters, or [`cStringUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3a), [`getCString:maxLength:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCString%3amaxLength%3aencoding%3a) or [`UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) for c-style strings), then operate on that (note some methods return const strings), then construct a new string using (e.g.) [`initWithCString:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithCString%3aencoding%3a). Keep in mind that, depending on what you're [trying to accomplish](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal), shifting bytes may not give you the result you expect, due to encoding issues and multibyte characters.

You can get the length of a string using [`length`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length), which is the number of characters in the string (also the size, in unichars, of a buffer to hold UTF-16 data, not including a null-terminator), or [`lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding%3a), which will tell you the size (number of bytes) needed for a buffer to hold the contents of the string (not including a null-terminator). [`maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding%3a) can also be used for a buffer size, though it may be larger than the actual necessary size. For variable-length encodings, the maximum size is the largest possible character size (e.g. 3 for UTF-8 encoded unichars) times the number of characters.

Looping and shifting is otherwise the same as in C: initialize the index variable to the lower bound (0) and loop until the index variable exceeds the upper bound.

```
NSUInteger i;
NSString *result=nil;
unichar *data;
NSRange dataRange = {0,0};
dataRange.length = [string length];
if ((data = malloc(dataRange.length * sizeof(unichar)))) {
    [string getCharacters:data range:dataRange];
    for (i=0; i < dataRange.length; ++i) {
        // shiftAmount is declared elsewhere
        data[i] <<= shiftAmount;
    }
    result = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:data length:dataRange.length];
} else {
    // malloc() failed; handle error
    ...
}
```

If the data isn't string data but bytes, [`NSData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/[`NSMutableData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
NSString * string = @"Anne";
int length = [string length];
for(int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"%C",character);
}
```

Output:

```
A
n
n
e
```